# Прописная и строчная буква

Tags: прописная-строчная

Кризисы приходят и уходят, а земля вачская остается навсегда.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, вачская с прописной буквы или со строчной?

Answer (score 2):

Если судить по написанию "земля Русская", "земля Саратовская", то "земля Вачская". Это образное название географических объектов, правда, чаще образные названия даются государствам, но бывает, что и областям. Правило говорит, что в этом случае с прописной буквы пишется или первое слово, или слово, подчёркивающее характерный признак объекта: Страна тюльпанов. У нас характерный признак - принадлежность Саратову, но не просто притяжательное прилагательное, а именно образ просторов-как Родина . Поэтому лучше с прописной буквы писать Вачская.

Comment: Я тоже так думала, но меня смутило частое написание Вачская с маленькой (строчной) буквы. Спасибо, что вы мне подсказываете

Comment: С маленькой пишут строго по правилам притяжательных прилагательных, но у Вас же поэтический, торжественный стиль, имеете право.